# Click checkbox in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to click this checkbox, I have tried almost all the XPATH but it's not working.

The following class is from the GOOGLE Forms > Include FORM in Email

```
<div id="c9" class="quantumWizTogglePapercheckboxEl appsMaterialWizTogglePapercheckboxCheckbox docssharedWizToggleLabeledControl freebirdThemedCheckbox freebirdMaterialWidgetsToggleLabeledCheckbox isCheckedNext" jscontroller="EcW08c" jsaction="keydown:I481le;dyRcpb:dyRcpb;click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue; focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd;" jsshadow="" jsname="gZKGbc" aria-label="Include form in email" tabindex="0" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false"><div class="quantumWizTogglePapercheckboxInk exportInk"></div><div class="quantumWizTogglePapercheckboxInnerBox exportInnerBox"></div><div class="quantumWizTogglePapercheckboxCheckMarkContainer"><div class="quantumWizTogglePapercheckboxCheckMark"><div class="quantumWizTogglePapercheckboxShort exportCheck"></div><div class="quantumWizTogglePapercheckboxLong exportCheck"></div></div></div></div>
```

There's another class which is similar to above but has a different checkbox.

```
<div id="c6" class="quantumWizTogglePapercheckboxEl appsMaterialWizTogglePapercheckboxCheckbox docssharedWizToggleLabeledControl freebirdThemedCheckbox freebirdMaterialWidgetsToggleLabeledCheckbox isCheckedNext" jscontroller="EcW08c" jsaction="keydown:I481le;dyRcpb:dyRcpb;click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue; focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd;" jsshadow="" jsname="JUdOvc" aria-label="Collect email addresses" tabindex="0" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false"><div class="quantumWizTogglePapercheckboxInk exportInk"></div><div class="quantumWizTogglePapercheckboxInnerBox exportInnerBox"></div><div class="quantumWizTogglePapercheckboxCheckMarkContainer"><div class="quantumWizTogglePapercheckboxCheckMark"><div class="quantumWizTogglePapercheckboxShort exportCheck"></div><div class="quantumWizTogglePapercheckboxLong exportCheck"></div></div></div></div>
```

I tried with the following:

```
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'appsMaterialWizTogglePapercheckboxCheckbox')]")
```

None of them works and generates the error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(text(), 'appsMaterialWizTogglePapercheckboxCheckbox')]"}
```

Comment: With your xpath you are looking for text, but the text that you pass in is actually a class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'appsMaterialWizTogglePapercheckboxCheckbox'` is not a text, but *class name*. Try

```
"//*[contains(@class, 'appsMaterialWizTogglePapercheckboxCheckbox')]"
```

**Edit**

Try to use `aria-label` attribute instead of `class` attribute to select correct checkbox:

```
"//*[@aria-label='Include form in email']"
```

Comment: It does works but selects another checkbox "Collect email addresses" not the particular.

Comment: @Karan please update your question with HTML for both checkboxes so I can provide with unique selector

Comment: @Karan try updated XPath. Checkboxes have different `aria-label` attributes, so you can use `[@aria-label='Include form in email']` and `[@aria-label='Collect email addresses']` to select required checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to search by `id`, as this is unique for an element.

```
"//*[@id='c9']"
```